# References on almost complex structures on spheres

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry

I'm looking for a proof of that the only spheres with almost complex structure are $S^2$ and $S^6$. I've googled "almost complex structure sphere", but all I get is comments saying that "this fact is well-known".

Are there good write-ups on this topic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: References are given at the beginning of Chapter VI of the book "Almost complex and complex structures" by C.C. Hsiung. It uses characteristic classes and cohomology operations to get obstructions.

Comment: One must be careful with the last chapters of the book BCnrd mentioned, I think Dr. Bryant has said on this site that there is an error in them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this "well known fact" was proved first by Borel and Serre,

Borel, A., Serre, J. P.: Groupes de Lie et puissances réduites de Steenrod. Amer. J. Math.75, 409–448 (1953)

For a more detailed timeline, see [Differential Geometry: Geometry in mathematical physics and related topics](http://books.google.de/books?id=1s-UePH5KfAC&pg=PA100&lpg=PA100&dq=almost+complex+structure+on+spheres+S%5E2+S%5E6&source=bl&ots=HZDRuFRPB6&sig=T_jsFRQlEIhPPBTvfGHOZp5426I&hl=de&ei=9qn3S9ShO6KemwPUgenHAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBTgU#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Greene and Yau (p.100).

Or as BCnrd suggested [Almost complex and complex structures](http://books.google.de/books?id=-yz03cskUOgC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=almost+complex+structure+on+spheres+S%5E2+S%5E6&source=bl&ots=KxGtjBRHCP&sig=AANscUt-KM5KILqIaPMJ1zRId94&hl=de&ei=9qn3S9ShO6KemwPUgenHAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAjgU#v=onepage&q&f=false) by C. C. Hsiung (Chapter VI)

Answer (score 4):

Peter May's A Concise Introduction to Algebraic Topology has a proof sketch on pages 207-209. It is in subsection 4 called "The Chern character; almost complex structures on spheres" in chapter 24 "An Introduction to K-theory".

Answer (score 4):

[Konstantis & Parton - Almost complex structures on spheres](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03883) is a self-contained paper which explains the proof very clearly.