# Which Spheres are Complex Manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [complex structure on S^n](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11664/complex-structure-on-sn)

The two sphere $S^2$ is a real manifold of dimension $2$, while the three sphere $S^3$ is a real manifold of dimension $3$. Now $S^2$ is a complex manifold, while $S^3$ being odd dimensional is not. Is it true that all spheres of the form $S^{2N}$ are complex manifolds?

Answer (score 13):

It's a nice exercise in characteristic classes to show that S^4k for all k are NOT complex manifolds.

**EDIT:** I will answer Charlie's comment here and provide a sketch of the proof.

Let $\omega=TS^{4k}$ be the tangent space to the $4k$-sphere. If $S^{4k}$ was actually a complex manifold then $\omega$ would be a complex vector bundle. In this case the complexification of the underlying real vector bundle $\omega_{\mathbb{R}}$ would be canonically isomorphic to the Whitney sum $\omega\oplus \bar{\omega}$ (Milnor&Stasheff page 176). Now by corollary 15.5 in Milnor&Stasheff 
$$p_k(\omega_{\mathbb{R}})=c_k^2(\omega)-2c_{k-1}c_{k+1}(\omega)+\cdots\mp 2c_{2k}(\omega)$$

This then shows that the top Pontrjagin number
$$< p_k,[S^{4k}]>=<\mp 2c_{2k},[S^{4k}]>=\mp 4$$
but we also know that spheres are boundries of an oriented manifold and thus have higher Pontrjagin number 0. Contradiction.

On another note, according to C.C. Hsiung's book [*Almost Complex and Complex Structures*](http://books.google.com/books?id=-yz03cskUOgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=complex%2520structures%2520on%2520spheres&f=false) on page 233 he says "In fact, the absence of an almost complex structure on $S^{4k}$ for $k\geq 1$ and $S^{2n}$ for $n\geq 4$ was proved by Wu and jointly Borel and Serre respectively."

Comment: Don't characteristic classes in fact prove that $S^{2k}$ for $k\geq 3$ aren't? I thought it boiled down to $(k-1)!$ needs to divide 2, or else the characteristic classes obstruct, leaving $S^2$, $S^4$ and $S^6$, and $S^4$ needs to be ruled out by hand.

Comment: @Charlie, I think you mean $k>3$.

Comment: Ah, of course, $>$ not $\geq$.

Comment: As an almost complex structure on $X$ endows $TX$ with the structure of a complex vector bundle, doesn't your argument show that these spheres don't even admit almost complex structures, let alone integrable ones?

Answer (score 11):

That's VERY much false.  This [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25557/references-on-almost-complex-structures-on-spheres) is looking for a reference to the fact that $S^2$ and $S^6$ are the only ones with even almost complex structures, and it's open if $S^6$ admits a complex structure (the almost complex structure known is not one)

Edit: Other questions on complex structures on spheres are [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1973/is-there-a-complex-structure-on-the-6-sphere) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11664/complex-structure-on-sn/11667#11667).