# Is $\mathbb{CP}^2$ with a line collapsed a complex analytic space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Consider the quotient space of $\mathbf{CP}^2$ obtained by collapsing a line (a $\mathbf{CP}^1$) to a point. Is this a complex analytic space (in a natural way)?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Grauert criterion says that a curve on a complex analytic surface can be contracted (in the analytic setting) if and only if its normal bundle is negative, so the answer to your question should be *no*.

Comment: Unless I'm confused, this quotient space is $S^4$, and there is no complex *manifold* structure on this if that's any help. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29964/which-spheres-are-complex-manifolds

Comment: Todd: you're not confused; there's not even an almost-complex structure on the 4-sphere. May I suggest that you make this into an answer?

Comment: Well, a priori the quotient could be some *singular* analytic space homeomorphic to $S^4$. How can one exclude this possibility without using Grauert criterion?

Comment: @DannyRuberman Thanks. Francesco's last comment summarizes well why I hesitated making my comment an answer.

Comment: What would be an holomorphic function near the singular point ?

Comment: @ToddTrimble (and Francesco): I was reading too fast and ignored the phrasing of the question (analytic space vs. surface). Could one have alternatively argued using Mumford's criterion http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.468.8913&rep=rep1&type=pdf, using the fact that this space is a smooth manifold?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is *no*, because of the following general result.

> **Theorem (Grauert's contractibility criterion).** Let $X$ be a smooth complex surface and let $E \subset X$ be a connected curve in $X$, with irreducible components $E_i$. Then there exists an analytic contraction $$\pi \colon X \to Y$$
>   of $E$ to a point $p \in Y$, where $Y$ is a (possibly singular) complex surface, if and only if the intersection matrix $(E_i \cdot E_j)$ is negative defined.

If $E \subset \mathbb{CP}^2$ is a line, then $E^2=1$ and so $E$ cannot be analytically contracted to a point.

For a reference, see [K. Matsuki, *Introduction to the Mori program*, Theorem 4-6-25 p.234].